# ContentDialog in Windows Phone 8.1 doesn't close properly, even though it's hidden

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I've several ContentDialog's in my Universal WP8 application. The problem is that when I just used one on page A and I navigate to page B and try to use the second one my application crashes with the error WINRT: Only one ContentDialog can be open at one time.

I don't use the basic buttons, but I've implemented buttons myself with Commands like you can see below.

```
    <ContentDialog x:Name="contentDialog"
x:Class="ThuisApp.Content.PostComment"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ThuisApp.Content"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="Post comment" DataContext="{Binding PostCommentViewmodel, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource ViewmodelLocator}}" Foreground="{StaticResource MainAspectColor}" FullSizeDesired="True">

<Grid Margin="0">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid Margin="0,0,0,12">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="12"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" BorderBrush="{StaticResource MainAspectColor}" BorderThickness="1" >
                <Grid>
                    <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/profile-placeholder.png"/>
                    <Image Source="{Binding Report.userID, Converter={StaticResource UserIdToImageUrlConverter}}"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding Report.username}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="{StaticResource ReportUserFont}" FontSize="{StaticResource ReportUserFontSize}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" Margin="0" Grid.Column="2" Foreground="{StaticResource ReportHeaderTextColor}"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Report.createDate, Converter={StaticResource TimePassedConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="{StaticResource ReportHeaderInfoFontSize}" FontFamily="{StaticResource ReportHeaderInfoFont}" FontWeight="Light" Grid.Column="3" Foreground="{StaticResource ReportHeaderTextColor}"/>
        </Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Name="body" Style="{StaticResource MessageDialogContentStyle}" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="140" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Text="{Binding Report.Message}" FontFamily="{StaticResource ItemBodyFont}" FontSize="{StaticResource ItemBodyFontSize}" Foreground="{StaticResource ItemBodyTextColor}"/>
        <TextBox Header="Comment" TextWrapping="Wrap" MinHeight="140" Text="{Binding Comment, Mode=TwoWay}" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource TextBoxHeader}" SelectionHighlightColor="{StaticResource TextBoxSelectionHighlightColor}"/>
        <!-- Content body -->
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,12,0,0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Content="post comment" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,0,12,0" Style="{StaticResource FullColorButton}" Background="#FF42A5F5" Foreground="White" Command="{Binding PostComment}"/>
        <Button Content="cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource FullColorButton}" Background="#FF42A5F5" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Cancel}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I handle the Init and closing by sending messages by using the Messenger of Galasoft to the View.

```
    public Constructor
     Messenger.Default.Register<bool>(true, MessengerToken.OpenClosePostCommentPopup, OpenClosePostCommentPopup);
    }

    public async void OpenClosePostCommentPopup(bool isOpen)
    {
        if (isOpen && !_isDialogOpen)
        {
            _dialog = new PostComment();
            _dialog.Opened += dialog_Opened;
            _dialog.Closed += dialog_Closed;
            await _dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        else
        {
            _dialog.Hide();
            _dialog = null;
        }
    }

    void dialog_Closed(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        _isDialogOpen = false;
    }

    void dialog_Opened(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogOpenedEventArgs args)
    {
        _isDialogOpen = true;
    }
```

I know that it hits the .Hide and that it hides, but for some reason it still thinks it is open somehow. Does anyone has any idea?

By request: Below is the command that gets called to open the box

```
PostComment = new RelayCommand<ReportDB>(item =>
        {
            //Load information into VM
            Messenger.Default.Send<ReportDB>(item, MessengerToken.LoadReportToComment);
            //Opens the popup
            Messenger.Default.Send<bool>(true, MessengerToken.OpenClosePostCommentPopup);
        });
```

Comment: Can we see the code of the commands? The Cancel and the postcomment command?

Comment: CQ how is the dialog started? What code leads up to it.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same issue on the Windows 10 Universal App with a Problem mouse(double click). So if you double click the button, and the first dialog will show but the second dialog has been prevented. So the solution is Don't allow two ContentDialog opened at the same time.

Here is my solution in order to avoid the exception:

```
    private static List<MessageDialog> dialogOpenQueue = new List<MessageDialog>();
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public MessageDialog()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private static bool quickShowRunning = false;

    public async static Task QuickShowAsync(string title, string message)
    {
        MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog() { Title = title, Message = message };
        dialogOpenQueue.Add(dialog);
        if (quickShowRunning)
            return;
        quickShowRunning = true;

        for (int i = 0; i< dialogOpenQueue.Count; i++)
        {
            await dialogOpenQueue[i].ShowAsync();
            dialogOpenQueue.RemoveAt(i);
            i--;
        }
        quickShowRunning = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the result from the specific dialog that you submitted, and avoid the explicit queueing and looping, try the approach in ["Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time." error while opening another contentdialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018346/only-a-single-contentdialog-can-be-open-at-any-time-error-while-opening-anoth/47986634#47986634)