# "Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time." error while opening another contentdialog

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog` to show a confirmation. And based on the response from the first dialog I would (or would not) show another dialog. But, when I am trying to open the second content dialog it throws : "Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time." error. Even though in the UI, first dialog would be closed but somehow I am still not able to open the second dialog. Any idea?

Comment: Throw some code, let us know how you do that.

Answer (score 10):

I have created some code to handle this type of conundrum in my Apps:

```
public static class ContentDialogMaker
{
    public static async void CreateContentDialog(ContentDialog Dialog, bool awaitPreviousDialog) { await CreateDialog(Dialog, awaitPreviousDialog); }
    public static async Task CreateContentDialogAsync(ContentDialog Dialog, bool awaitPreviousDialog) { await CreateDialog(Dialog, awaitPreviousDialog); }

    static async Task CreateDialog(ContentDialog Dialog, bool awaitPreviousDialog)
    {
        if (ActiveDialog != null)
        {
            if (awaitPreviousDialog)
            {
                await DialogAwaiter.Task;
                DialogAwaiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
            }
            else ActiveDialog.Hide();
        }
        ActiveDialog = Dialog;
        ActiveDialog.Closed += ActiveDialog_Closed;
        await ActiveDialog.ShowAsync();
        ActiveDialog.Closed -= ActiveDialog_Closed;
    }

    public static ContentDialog ActiveDialog;
    static TaskCompletionSource<bool> DialogAwaiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    private static void ActiveDialog_Closed(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosedEventArgs args) { DialogAwaiter.SetResult(true); }
}
```

To use these Methods, you need to create the ContentDialog and its content in a variable, then pass the variable, and bool into the Method.

Use CreateContentDialogAsync(), if you require a callback in your app code, say if you have a button in your Dialog, and you want wait for a button press, and then get the value from the form in code after the dialog.

Use CreateContentDialog(), if you don't need to wait for the Dialog to complete in your UI Code.

Use awaitPreviousDialog to wait for the previous dialog to complete before showing the next Dialog, or set false, to remove the previous Dialog, then show the next Dialog, say, if you want to show an Error Box, or the next Dialog is more important.

Example:

```
await ContentDialogMaker.CreateContentDialogAsync(new ContentDialog
{
    Title = "Warning",
    Content = new TextBlock
    {
        Text = "Roaming Appdata Quota has been reached, if you are seeing this please let me know via feedback and bug reporting, this means that any further changes to data will not be synced across devices.",
        TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap
    },
    PrimaryButtonText = "OK"
}, awaitPreviousDialog: true);
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Here's my example code: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50486830/only-a-single-contentdialog-can-be-open-at-any-time

Comment: How do you attach events with this helper?

Comment: @HaBo you could get the instance from ContentDialogMaker.ActiveDialog (do a null check), removing the await and storing the task after CreateContentDialogAsync, get the instance then awaiting, or you could modify the Helper to add desired events.

Answer (score 5):

William Bradley's approach above is good. Just to polish it up a bit, here is an extension method to submit and await the showing of a content dialog; the dialog will be shown after all the other content dialogs that have already been submitted. Note: by the time the user clicks through earlier backlogged dialogs you may no longer want to show the dialog that you have submitted; to indicate this you may pass a predicate that will be tested after the other dialogs have been dismissed.

```
static public class ContentDialogExtensions
{
    static public async Task<ContentDialogResult> EnqueueAndShowIfAsync( this ContentDialog contentDialog, Func<bool> predicate = null)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<Null> currentDialogCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<Null>();
        TaskCompletionSource<Null> previousDialogCompletion = null;

        // No locking needed since we are always on the UI thread.
        if (!CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess) { throw new NotSupportedException("Can only show dialog from UI thread."); }
        previousDialogCompletion = ContentDialogExtensions.PreviousDialogCompletion;
        ContentDialogExtensions.PreviousDialogCompletion = currentDialogCompletion;

        if (previousDialogCompletion != null) {
            await previousDialogCompletion.Task;
        }
        var whichButtonWasPressed = ContentDialogResult.None;
        if (predicate == null || predicate()) {
            whichButtonWasPressed = await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        currentDialogCompletion.SetResult(null);
        return whichButtonWasPressed;
    }

    static private TaskCompletionSource<Null> PreviousDialogCompletion = null;
}
```

Another way might be to use a SemaphoreSlim(1,1).

Comment: Forgot to mention: public class Null { private Null() {} }

Comment: P.S. For tips on having the ContentDialog always be centered in the window, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384062/contentdialog-not-aligning-to-center-on-uwp

Answer (score 4):

"Only a single ContentDialog can be **open** at a time"

This statement is not entirely true.  You can only **ShowAsync** one ContentDialog at a time.  All you need to do is **hide** the current ContentDialog before opening another one. Then, after the "await ShowAsync" of the second ContentDailog, your simply call "var T = this.ShowAync()" to unhide it.  Example:

```
public sealed partial class MyDialog2 : ContentDialog
{
    ...
}

public sealed partial class MyDialog1 : ContentDialog
{
    ...

    private async void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Hide MyDialog1
        this.Hide(); 

        // Show MyDialog2 from MyDialog1
        var C = new MyDialog2();
        await C.ShowAsync();

        // Unhide MyDialog1
        var T = ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is slightly old, but one simpler solution instead of going through all this pain is to just register a callback for the ContentDialog_Closed event. By this point you can be sure the previous dialog has been closed, and can open your next dialog. :)

Answer (score 1):

I like this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/47986634/942855, this will allow us ot handle binding all events.

So extended it a little to check the multiple calls to show dialog.

```
 private int _dialogDisplayCount;
 private async void Logout_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {    
                _dialogDisplayCount++;
                ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog
                {
                    Title = "Logout",
                    Content = "Are you sure, you want to Logout?",
                    PrimaryButtonText = "Yes",
                    CloseButtonText = "No"
                };
                noWifiDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += ContentDialog_PrimaryButtonClick;
                //await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
                await noWifiDialog.EnqueueAndShowIfAsync(() => _dialogDisplayCount);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _rootPage.NotifyUser(exception.ToString(), NotifyType.DebugErrorMessage);
            }
            finally
            {
                _dialogDisplayCount = 0;
            }
        }
```

**modified predicate**

```
public class Null { private Null() { } }
    public static class ContentDialogExtensions
    {
        public static async Task<ContentDialogResult> EnqueueAndShowIfAsync(this ContentDialog contentDialog, Func<int> predicate = null)
        {
            TaskCompletionSource<Null> currentDialogCompletion = new TaskCompletionSource<Null>();

            // No locking needed since we are always on the UI thread.
            if (!CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.HasThreadAccess) { throw new NotSupportedException("Can only show dialog from UI thread."); }
            var previousDialogCompletion = _previousDialogCompletion;
            _previousDialogCompletion = currentDialogCompletion;

            if (previousDialogCompletion != null)
            {
                await previousDialogCompletion.Task;
            }
            var whichButtonWasPressed = ContentDialogResult.None;
            if (predicate == null || predicate() <=1)
            {
                whichButtonWasPressed = await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
            }
            currentDialogCompletion.SetResult(null);
            return whichButtonWasPressed;
        }

        private static TaskCompletionSource<Null> _previousDialogCompletion;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time.**

That is a fact. (*I was really surprised, but just for a moment*)
You can't have more than one at any time and it is more like guideline from Microsoft, because it's really messy to have multiple dialogs on top of each other filled with content.

Try to change your **UX** to display only one sophisticated *ContentDialog* and for all other messages use **MessageDialog** - it supports multiple buttons(*only two for phones, but more on desktop*) for user response but without *Checkboxes* or similar "smart"-content stuff.

In my case MessageDialogs were really helpful, but in some areas I used *chained* ContentDialogs but for that you **must** *await* the first one, and open second right after without any exceptions. In your case it seems like ContentDialog was not fully closed when you tried to open next one.

Hope it helps!