# Why can't I open a ContentDialog after the first has closed?

Tags: c#, uwp

I have an applicaition which creates books, and then pages. I store the information on new books in an ObservableCollection which automatically updates an SQLite db on CollectionChanged. The list also powers a list view of which the data source is the selected item.

The problem I have is that, intermitently, after creating a new book using a content dialog I get the error below when I try and open a second dialog to create the page.

**WinRT information: Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time.**

I have a callback for the ContentDialog.Closed event so I can be sure its closed, but the exception still gets thrown!!!

Does anybody know why this would be?

the error happens on "await newRecipeDialog.ShowAsync();" Code Below:

```
    private async void AddCookBook_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CookBookDialog newCookBookDialog = new CookBookDialog();
        newCookBookDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += NewCookBookDialog_PrimaryButtonClick;
        newCookBookDialog.Opened += NewCookBookDialog_Opened;
        newCookBookDialog.Closed += NewCookBookDialog_Closed;
        await newCookBookDialog.ShowAsync();
    }

    private void NewCookBookDialog_Closed(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        textBlock.Text = "Closed";
    }

    private void NewCookBookDialog_Opened(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogOpenedEventArgs args)
    {
        textBlock.Text = "Open";
    }

    private void NewCookBookDialog_PrimaryButtonClick(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogButtonClickEventArgs args)
    {
        p_App.DataBase.CookBooks.Add(((CookBookDialog)sender).CookBook);
    }

    private async void CreateRecipe_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        RecipeDialog newRecipeDialog = new RecipeDialog();
        newRecipeDialog.PrimaryButtonClick += NewRecipeDialog_PrimaryButtonClick;
        await newRecipeDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018346/only-a-single-contentdialog-can-be-open-at-any-time-error-while-opening-anoth) SO question help?

Comment: No, that is a question about opening them at the same time. This is a question about opening them one after the other.

Comment: I have tested your code in my side. It works well and I cannot reproduce your issue. The issue seems to be in your custom content dialog: `CookBookDialog` and `RecipeDialog`. Replace the `RecipeDialog` to `ContentDialog` to see if it can reproduce the issue. If not, please upload the code of `CookBookDialog`.