# Queuing ContentDialog in uwp

Tags: asynchronous, uwp, controls

It is possible to queue ContentDialog's and show it  after another is closed?
I used this to find ContentDialog

```
var popups = VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current);
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var item in popups)
        {
            if (item.Child is ContentDialog)
                i++;
        }
        if (i == 0)
        {
            //show ContentDialog
        }
        else
            // add to my listOfContentDialog
```

But if I've try to open more ContentDialog's at once it throw an exception that operation is started incorrectly.

**UPDATE**
According to Jayden Gu - MSFT my working code

```
private List<string> testowa_lista = new List<string>();

    private async void Komunikat_siatki(string v)
    {
        if(mozeWyskoczyc)
        {
            mozeWyskoczyc = false;
            //my internal code to generate ContentDialog using v string
            testowa_lista.Remove(v);
            mozeWyskoczyc = true;
            if (testowa_lista.Count > 0)
            {
                var i = testowa_lista.First();
                Komunikat_siatki(i);
            }                    
        }
        else
        {
            testowa_lista.Add(v);
        }
    }
```

Comment: May I know how many ContentDialogs you want to queue? I would try to provide a solution according to that..

Comment: The namber of ContentDialogs are dynamic (max 5)

Comment: There is another approach described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018346/only-a-single-contentdialog-can-be-open-at-any-time-error-while-opening-anoth/47986634#47986634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only one ContentDialog can be shown at a time.

If one `ContentDialog` is shown, we can not show another `ContentDialog`. When you add the `ShowAsync` method in the `LostFocus` event of the `TextBox` and use Tap button, it will show two `ContentDialog` at same time.

You should be able to add a bool field to save to state of if the `ContentDialog` can be shown.

For example:

```
private async void Text_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (dialogCanShow)
    {
        dialogCanShow = false;
        var textBox= sender as TextBox;
        var contentDialog = new ContentDialog();
        contentDialog.Title = textBox.Name;
        contentDialog.CloseButtonText = "Close";
        await contentDialog.ShowAsync();
        dialogCanShow = true;
    }
}
```

When we close the `ContentDialog`, the cursor will show in the current `TextBox`.

Comment: Partly what i want... it's prevent from opening more then one ContentDialog but not create queue.

Comment: @kdn29 take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33018346/only-a-single-contentdialog-can-be-open-at-any-time-error-while-opening-anoth/47986634#47986634

Answer (score 2):

I've created a function that replicates the functionality of the JavaScript `Alert()` function. It creates a ContentDialog and adds this to a queue. An event handler ensures that when the Dialog is closed, it removes itself from the queue and calls `ShowAsync()` for the next Dialog in the queue, assuming there is one.

```cs
sealed partial class App : Application
{
    ...
    private static List<ContentDialog> DialogQueue { get; } = new List<ContentDialog>();

    public static async void Alert(string text)
    {
        var Dialog = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = text,
            CloseButtonText = "OK"
            ...
        };
        App.DialogQueue.Add(Dialog);

        // Add event handler for when dialog closed:
        Dialog.Closed += Dialog_Closed;

        if (App.DialogQueue.Count == 1) // Only one in queue
        {
            await Dialog.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
    // Event handler for when dialog closed:
    private static async void Dialog_Closed(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosedEventArgs args)
    {
        App.DialogQueue.Remove(sender);
        if (App.DialogQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            await App.DialogQueue[0].ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I've put the static function inside App.xaml.cs (along with the queue and dialog closed event handler), so you call it like `App.Alert("Hello world")` although you could put it inside its own class. Of course, you can add parameters to `Alert()` to populate the different properties of the ContentDialog.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a message dialog instead.

```
await new MessageDialog("First").ShowAsync();

await new MessageDialog("Second").ShowAsync();
```

Comment: No it's not what I need

Answer (score 0):

You may store them in some collection and then show them one after one:

```
List<ContentDialog> dialogs = new List<ContentDialog>()
{
    contentDialog1,
    contentDialog2,
    contentDialog3
};

foreach (ContentDialog dialog in dialogs)
{
    await dialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: In UWP only one ContentDialog can by opened at one time. Your code throw an exception.

Comment: Have you tried it? It works for me since the execution of the `foreach` loop will continue once one dialog is closed.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not working. Throw exception that only one ContentDialog can by opened at one time

Comment: "An exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in kdnmed.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: W danym momencie tylko jeden element ContentDialog może być otwarty.
Operacja asynchroniczna nie została poprawnie rozpoczęta."

Comment: That's weird, no exception for me... Can you post the whole code so I could look?

Comment: I've for 5 textbox. Each one when lost focus calculate some code. When the result is out of range the content dialog is show. The problem is when the user press TAB button and Content dialog appears next textbox lost focus and force to show next content dialog.. maybe the problem is that list of content dialog changed dynamicly?

Comment: Then you should have some variable indicating whether any `ContentDialog` is opened and check it before opening another.

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to queue multiple content dialogs you may try this :

```
            int count = 1;  //count is used to simply to have dynamic content in the dialogs
            private async void startCreatingDialog()
            {
                var result = await createDialog(count.ToString()).ShowAsync();
                if (result == ContentDialogResult.Primary)
                {
                    //create a new dialog based on user's input 
                    count++;
                    startCreatingDialog();
                }

            }
            private ContentDialog createDialog(string content)
            {
                ContentDialog contentDialog = new ContentDialog()
                {                
                    Content = content,
                    //clicking on the primarybutton will create the next ContentDialog
                    PrimaryButtonText = "Show another dialog",                        
                    SecondaryButtonText = "Cancel"
                };

                return contentDialog;

            }
```

To start showing the dialog queue you need to call `startCreatingDialog()` and rest will be handled according the user's choice..

Hope this helps..