# Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time errors

Tags: uwp

I've inherited a complex C# / UWP application that is riddled with crashes due to this problem: "Only a single ContentDialog can be open at any time".

The original developer of the app put in a lot of dialogs, many in response to error conditions, and apparently did not attempt to keep track of whether or not he was trying to open a dialog on top of another one.

Is there some kind of brute-force way I can write something that either closes whatever dialog is open or at least lets me detect that condition before opening another dialog?

I realize that I should understand the app in detail and try to figure out the root cause of the problem. Unfortunately, it is a very large and very important app that is past its due date and the customer just needs a quick fix to get it working.

Comment: follow link question already posted [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33018346/11362349)

Answer (score 1):

Actually the recommend and best approach is to maintain the dialogs from your source code.

And if you really need a quick fix, please see the following [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4faa5cdb-b49a-4ac5-9d5e-cbd9355b8821/uwpc-how-to-detect-if-a-contentdialog-is-visible?forum=wpdevelop) from David. Use this method: [VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper.getopenpopups) to detect the opened popups, which also contains the contentdialog you need. Then do what you want:

```
 var popups=VisualTreeHelper.GetOpenPopups(Window.Current);
        foreach (var popup in popups)
        {
            if(popup.Child is ContentDialog)
            {

            }
        }
```

But I need to clarify again, it's actually not best practice so it's better not to use VirtualTreeHelper, as you have the source code. I strongly recommend you check the source code to maintain all your dialogs yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, it works for me

Step 1 :- Create a class

```
public static class ContentDialogMaker
    {
        public static async void CreateContentDialog(ContentDialog Dialog, bool awaitPreviousDialog) { await CreateDialog(Dialog, awaitPreviousDialog); }
        public static async Task CreateContentDialogAsync(ContentDialog Dialog, bool awaitPreviousDialog) { await CreateDialog(Dialog, awaitPreviousDialog); }

        static async Task CreateDialog(ContentDialog Dialog, bool awaitPreviousDialog)
        {
            if (ActiveDialog != null)
            {
                if (awaitPreviousDialog)
                {
                    ActiveDialog.Hide();
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (Info.Status)
                    {
                        case AsyncStatus.Started:
                            Info.Cancel();
                            break;
                        case AsyncStatus.Completed:
                            Info.Close();
                            break;
                        case AsyncStatus.Error:
                            break;
                        case AsyncStatus.Canceled:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            ActiveDialog = Dialog;
            ActiveDialog.Closing += ActiveDialog_Closing;
            Info = ActiveDialog.ShowAsync();
        }
        public static IAsyncInfo Info;
        private static void ActiveDialog_Closing(ContentDialog sender, ContentDialogClosingEventArgs args)
        {
            ActiveDialog = null;
        }

        public static ContentDialog ActiveDialog;
    }
```

Step 2 - Call that class for showing a popup

```
ContentDialog dialog = new ContentDialog
            {
                Title = title,
                Content = message,
                CloseButtonText = "Ok"
            };
            await ContentDialogMaker.CreateContentDialogAsync(dialog, true);
```

Thanks!!!